# Is there a way to set the value of one key as the same as the value of another key in the same object in JS?

Tags: javascript, object

I want to know if there is a way to access the value of a key to add as the value of another key in the same object.

For example I want:

```
obj = {key1: 'apple', key2: 'applesauce'};
```

I tried `obj = {key1: 'apple', key2: this.key1 + 'sauce'}`

Also tried `obj = {key1: 'apple', key2: key1 + 'sauce'}`

I want it so that updating `key1` automatically updates `key2`.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it with a getter.

```js
obj = {
  key1: 'apple',
  get key2() {
    return this.key1 + 'sauce';
  }
}

console.log(obj.key2);
obj.key1 = 'awesome';
console.log(obj.key2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically, not at declaration, not that I know of. You can't refer to the object inside what is basically an object literal using `this` until the thing actually exists.

You could create a function to generate that object:

```
function keymaker(key) {
  return {
    key1: key,
    key2: key + 'sauce'
  }
}

obj = keymaker('apple');
```